# PHP Post Data not showing up on local wamp development area?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, post, wamp

I have tried searching for this weird issue, but can't find anything about it. I am also on a deadline of a week, and am going nuts.

My partner has installed WAMP on his local machine. Everything appears to be matching my setup. However when he goes to register on our site it simply does not submit the data. The browser acts like it sends it. It gives the data already sent, are you sure you want to resend data box.

However, the WAMP server shows nothing ever got there. The site comes up just fine after setting everything up like vhost. It is that POST data is not anywhere to be found by PHP.

We are using Codeigniter 2.1.4, PHP 5.3 and 5.4 (his) and Apache 2.2 or 2.4 (his). Register Globals is turned off.

I don't know if there is a bug, it has worked fine on two of our teams systems, his is just not doing it.

Any leads would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Try debugging what actually gets sent or not (not it seems like the browser sent it) with firebug (for firefox) or some similar chrome addons.

Comment: I have not tried this yet. I did want to add that this happens both on firefox and chrome exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your other teams systems are executing the same code and its working fine on their system but not your then their will be a platform issue.
Otherwise there might be another issue that generally occurs in case of form submissions.
The problem improper starting and closing of tags around form tag.
For example:

```
<form>
<div>
</form>
</div>
```

Check the code in firebug if its happening or not.

Comment: So I found this. I am not sure if this would trip up the system. The register button was a <button> but it did not have a type="submit" set.

    <button class="button btn btn-primary btn-large">Register</button>

Sorry I can't test it this second. He ran off for a bit.